# Is there any way to make a phone call directly without opening the Caller App using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the requirement to open the app without opening the Caller App. So I cannot use the [url_launcher package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) in flutter.

Kindly tell me another way to dial the number directly without opening the Caller App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package help you to call number's directly from your app: [flutter_phone_direct_caller](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller)